# ClassCastException in SpringBoot Logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, classcastexception

I'm getting an issue when my application starts up. The application fails when configuring log levels, on a ClassCastException `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel`.

I've tried setting `logging.level.root=INFO` in my `application.properties` and the same error occurs. Not sure what else to try.

I've just upgraded it to SpringBoot 2.x, specifically using this dependency BOM:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Please find the relevant parts of the dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.27:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.27:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.27:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
```

```
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |  |  |           \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.setLogLevels(LoggingApplicationListener.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeFinalLoggingLevels(LoggingApplicationListener.java:337)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:288)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:245)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:222)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
```

`application.properties`

```
logging.level.root=warn
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate=error
logging.level.com.my.package.name=error
```

[image: logging levels map causing problem]
Clearly the problem here is the values in this `levels` map are hashmaps, instead of strings.... Not sure why they are that way though.

Comment: Could you please share your `application.properties` file?

Comment: Hi @ShishirKumar. It has some organization specific related properties, but other than that it only has `logging.level.root=INFO`

Comment: That is weird, apparently the Spring code is getting confused when configuring the environment. You can find the offending code here, in case it helps: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/logging/LoggingApplicationListener.java

Comment: Maybe you could try to set a breakpoint in `Binder binder = Binder.get(environment);` and check what structure is returned as `binder`

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR ..  or using a package level logging.level.com.foo=DEBUG
Can you verify with this

Comment: can you share the whole pom? Why do you use spring-boot-dependencies? I have this issue when run mvn dependency:tree "[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'."

Comment: @Erwin unfortunately I cannot share the full pom, due to company related information. However I can assure you that the pieces posted are the only pieces relevant to this issue

Comment: @Victor please view my updated question

Comment: @user1001 please view my updated question

Comment: from your dependency tree it can be seen that there is slf4j which using the logging.level configuration in application.properties, and seem it came from spring-boot-starter-web. But you put dependency to spring-boot-dependencies which caused an issue "[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'."

Comment: I can see from the dependecny tree that logback core is excluded in springboot-starter   +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile

Comment: When you debug it.. What are the exact keys that you are seeing in level map?

Comment: the one thing i would check (but that's general debugging) is to double- and triple check the classpath, pom hierarchy etc to make sure that all versions line up and, especially, that at runtime, you don't have different versions of the same class loaded by different classloaders (e.g. when running in tomcat, you would have system classloaders, webapp classloaders, and then the springboot internal one)

Answer (score 1):

try setting the logging value to WARN and **debug=true** and have a check.

in your properties file set the values like this

```
logging.level.root=warn
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate=error
```

in **log4j.xml** it will look like this

```
<root>
        <level value="WARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>

</root>
```

for more details about logging in spring boot please read the below link
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/spring-boot-logging-configurations/

Comment: Thanks, please view my updated question. I've tried that and the same issue presents itself.

Answer (score -3):

Switch to logback, it gives you better control over your log levels and appenders.
See https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-logback-with-spring-boot